# Express/Swagger pre validation function for end points

Tags: node.js, rest, express, swagger

I am working on express js with swagger.

I have created some end points with defining respective controller and function call.

```
tabs/users:
# binds a127 app logic to a route
x-swagger-router-controller: tabs
get:
  description: Returns list of all users
  # used as the method name of the controller
  operationId: getUsers
  parameters:
    - name: name
      in: query
      description: name
      required: false
      type: string
  responses:
    "200":
      description: Success
      schema:
        # a pointer to a definition
        $ref: "#/definitions/TabResponse"
    # responses may fall through to errors
    default:
      description: Error
      schema:
        $ref: "#/definitions/ErrorResponse"
```

Like oprtionId getUsers, I have multiple functions.

Inside controller tabs.js I have functions like

```
function getUser(){
//business logic
}
```

Now I have one use case for every call to my end points I need to validate the token which user sent with each request is valid or not.

For this, I need to add validation function call to each controller function.

But I am looking for the central solution so that every call should go through validation function.

Please suggest your thoughts on it.

Comment: Create custom validator and check in all of your methods before you will process you object

Comment: But I am looking for any pre-call support or functionality (if present ) in swagger so that it can be centralize

Comment: You can add some validation in swagger BUT it will not validate your calls if you don't use swagger UI.

Comment: Write a middleware in your app.js(where you create you express app and register your app) file before you register your app. Do the validation in the middle ware.